# In MySQL stored procedures check if a local variable is null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

With the following example stored procedure

```
DECLARE Variable DOUBLE;
DECLARE Variable2 DOUBLE;
SELECT Something FROM Somewhere INTO Variable;

SELECT Something FROM SomewhereElse INTO Variable 2;

SELECT (Variable + Variable2);
```

If either Variable or Variable2 are NULL then the final SELECT will return null, what I would like is that if they are null they should be converted into 0.00 before the final SELECT, how do you do this? I already tried adding

```
SELECT 0.00 INTO Variable WHERE Variable IS NULL;
```

just above the final select but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(variable, 0) + COALESCE(variable2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want each variable null converted to 0 use the solution posted by Quassnoi

```
SELECT COALESCE(variable, 0) + COALESCE(variable2, 0)
```

if you want to have 0 if either variable is null then use

```
SELECT COALESCE(variable + variable2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quassnoi's correct, but it's even simpler (and a bit faster) to just coalesce the result:

```
 SELECT coalesce( Variable + Variable2, 0 );
```

This works because for almost all operators, any null operand will make the operation null:

```
   select 1 + null ; -- null
   select null + 1 ; -- null
   select null + null ; -- null
```

In the expression: `SELECT coalesce( Variable + Variable2, 0 );` the result of the addition expression `Variable + Variable2` is `coalesce` first argument; if that's null, coalesce returns its second argument, `0`, otherwise it returns the (non-null) value of its first argument, which is the sum we want.

The few operators and functions that don't return null for a null operand are those designed to work on nulls: `coalesce`, `is null`, `is not null`.

As kristof notes below, the value of the `select` expression is different using Quassnoi's expression, if only one variable is null: his will return the value of the non-null variable if one is null; mine will return zero if *either* variable is null. Which is "right" depends on your intent.

Comment: The two solutions aren't identical, Quassnoi's means that if only one variable is null the result is the other variable, that is the behavior I wanted.